# PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\.android\avd]!

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am facing problem in when i give write permission to avd it says

> PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.android\avd]!

i tried it many time but no use anyone android developer can me because i want to root virtual machine for my project.

Answer (score -1):

In windows, you need to update that environment variable in the starting before you run your interactive dos/PowerShell shell.

In Linux, it is as follows:

`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` path variable should point to the folder, which looks like below. 
[image].

After the update of either underlying Linux System or Android system, we, each time we run the bash terminal, we need to update/run `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` path variable. The `bash.bashrc` inside the `/etc` directory script runs everytime we open bash terminal.

Add, at the last line, your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file as below.

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/upg/Android/Sdk
```

Other than this, if you want to update other environmental variables, such as $PATH, you can update that too there in `bash.bashrc` file.